# Can I provide a json path in CSV file in postman

Tags: javascript, json, postman, data-driven-tests

I was trying to execute a postman collection that has many iteration. Data was provided in CSV format.

In each iteration i want to compare different nodes with expected messages provided in the datafile, for example,

sample collection:

```
{
    "message": [{
        "code": XYX,
        "abc": "how are you",
        "def": "where are you from"
        "ghi": "your name",
        "jkl": "place"
    }]
}
```

in 1st iteration - my test is as below

```
pm.response.json().message[0].code.to eql(data.ExpectedErrorMessage);
```

2nd iteration,

```
pm.response.json().message[0].abc.to eql(data.ExpectedErrorMessage);
```

and so on.

I have 100 + nodes and many arrays in the list. so its not feasible to write test for each node separately. Instead, i want to write a generic test and keep the response path in CSV file.

I tried by providing the path in below way in my data file.But i am unable to perform my test. I am getting the assertion error

```
[
  {
    "TC_ID": "TC_001",
    "TC_NAME": "abc",
    "path": "pm.response.json().message[0].code",
    "ExpectedErrorMessage": "XYZ"
  },
  {
    "TC_ID": "TC_002",
    "TC_NAME": "def",
    "path": "pm.response.json().message[0].abc",
    "ExpectedErrorMessage": "how are you"
  }
]
```

Comment: Since its json, why not add the function to the json object and then just call it, you can create a template for the function once then drop it in to the json everywhere you need it.

Comment: I have tried by using function. But no luck!!